# Converting a string obtained from a Pandas dataframe into individual lists per line

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, list, for-loop, python-itertools

test is a pandas dataframe converted to string.

```
strtest = (test.to_string())
print strtest
```

After conversion to string, I have the following output:

```
This is the first test file     98128612.12
This is the second test file    31236164.15
```

I am trying to have each line of the string placed into a list and printed out to look like this:

```
['This is the first test file','98128612.12']
['This is the second test file','31236164.15']
```

This are my codes when attempting to produce the output above in lists:

```
testlist = []

for row in strtest.iterrows():
        index, data = row
        testlist.append(data.tolist())

print testlist
```

However when I run it, I am having this error how do I solve this:

```
     for row in strtest.iterrows():
 AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'iterrows'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
testlist = test.values.tolist()
print (testlist)
[['This is the first test file', 98128612.12],
 ['This is the second test file', 31236164.15]]
```

Your code is possible use, [but not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24871316/2901002), because slow:

```
testlist = []
#change strtest to test DataFrame
for index, data in test.iterrows():
        testlist.append(data.tolist())

print (testlist)
```

Comment: I had tried testlist = test.values.tolist() previously however, I am only getting the float values. 'This is the first test file' string wasn't printed at all. The output is as follows: [98128612.12,31236164.15 ]

Comment: @SamT - So need `test.astype(str).values.tolist()` ?

Comment: thanks for the help but it doesn't seems to be working. Your second solution now generates this: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'iterrows'

Comment: @SamT - It is Series, you need `for index, data in test.reset_index().iterrows():`

Comment: @SamT - and for first solution `testlist = test.reset_index().values.tolist()`

Comment: @SamT - here [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) is used for convert index values to columns - it create DataFrame from Series